# Web Service with Java

Tags: java, web, service

Hy !

I this project. Collect some data from a web site. Like name, email etc..
So I want to make a web service in Java, to collect this data and then insert it into a database.

My question is. After I make the web service, in eclipse.
What should I have to do to make the web service automatically !?
Without open the eclipse project. When a user insert his data, those information goes directly into the database.
How can I make the project run at any time, without my intervention.

I only ask for guidance !
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem, is that you have some methods but don't know how to make them run when you receive some requests, or is it just to have your service always running ?

Comment: I want to make my service always run.

Comment: I don't know why someone is downvoting your question... This is an interesting question for everyone

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but there really isn't a lot of information; and questions like "how can I run my Java application as a service" are asked over and over again on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `nohup` command.

`nohup <commandToRunYourService> &`

This command is ignoring the hangup signal. So after that you can just use `Ctrl+C` to exit the command but your service will still be running